# Inner products Axioms

Tags: inner-products

Apologies for my use of angular brackets, I don't know how to do it properly.

Suppose $p(t) = a_{0}+a_{1}t^2+a_{2}t^2, q(t) = b_{0}+b_{1}t+b_{2}t^2 \in P_{2}(\mathbb{R}).$

Define $\langle p \;| \;q \rangle:=p(0)q(0)+p(1)q(1)+p(2)q(2).$ Is this an inner product on $P_{2}(\mathbb{R})$?

Now, to show whether or not this is an inner product we resort to our axioms.

$(1)$ $\langle p \;|\; p \rangle.\;$ is non-negative. For all $p\in P_{2}(\mathbb{R}).$

$(2)$ If $\langle p \;|\; p \rangle = 0$ this implies $p = 0.$ For all $p \in P_{2}(\mathbb{R}).$

$(3)$  $\langle ap+q\;|\;r\rangle = a \langle p\;|\;r \rangle+\langle q\;|\;r\rangle$ For all $p,q, r \in P_{2}(\mathbb{R}), a \in \mathbb{R}.$

$(4)$ $\langle p \;|\; q\rangle = \overline{\langle q \;|\; p\rangle}$ For all $p,q \in P_{2}(\mathbb{R}).$

I am able to show true/false for all axioms except for axiom $(2)$. So my attempt at axiom $(2)$, so we show the when the inner product of an element in our space with itself is $0$, then the element must be the zero polynomial? Correct?

If $\langle p \;|\; p\rangle = 0$, that is $[p(0)]^2+[p(1)]^2 +[p(2)]^2 = 0$. Clearly, equality holds when $p(0) =p(1) = p(2) = 0$. How would I argue this is indeed the zero polynomial?

Comment: The brackets are made using \langle and \rangle

Comment: Thanks, I'll be editing it now.

Comment: Does it have to be the zero polynomial? The question asks if it is an inner product, not show that it is one.  Then again, this is $P_2$...it would not be an inner product for $P_3$

Comment: I am losing some confidence, and deleted my previous comment, but I think you can argue that if $[p(0)]^{2} + [p(1)]^{2} + [p(2)]^{2} = 0$ and it is not the zero polynomial, then $p(t)$ has three roots, but $p(t)\in P_{2}(\mathbb{R})$, a contradiction.

Comment: Ah, I see, I was about to post that thanks for the confirmation :) I will just say since an n degree polynomial has at most n roots..

Comment: @Bobby In (2), $\langle p \mid p \rangle$ is a sum of squares. Squares of real numbers are $\geq 0$. So the only way for the sum to be zero is for all summands to be zero, i.e. $p(i)^2 = 0$ for all $i$. But then all the $p(i)$ must be zero, since the square of a non-zero real number is non-zero.